Falling to switch from 16-bit real mode to 32-bit protected mode
I am new to low level programming and I am writing a bootloader in assembly that switches from 16-bit real mode to 32-bit protected mode and loads a kernel. However, my bootloader stops working after loading the GDT, and the switch to protected mode doesn't seem to happen as expected.
The bootloader sets up a stack, prints messages, enables the A20 line, and loads a kernel.
I then set up a Global Descriptor Table (GDT) with null, code, and data segments.
I attempt to load the GDT, set the PE bit in CR0, and perform a far jump to a 32-bit code segment.
Debug messages are printed before and after key instructions to trace where the issue might be. The process halts after printing "Loading GDT...", and no further debug messages are printed. It seems that either the lgdt instruction or the subsequent steps are not executing correctly.
bootloader.asm
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl 
mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp

start:
    mov ax, 0x07C0
    add ax, 288      ; stack pointer
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x0100

    ; Display message 
    mov si, loading_msg
    call print_string

    ; Load kernel at 0x1000:0x0000
    mov bx, 0x1000   
    call load_kernel

    ; Message that kernel loaded
    mov si, debugg_msg
    call print_string

    ; Enable A20 bit
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al

    mov si, debugg_msg2     ; loading gdt...
    call print_string   

%include 'gdt.asm'

    mov si, debugg_msg3     ; switching to 32 bit protected mode
    call print_string

switch_to_32bit:
    cli ; 1. disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; 2. load the GDT descriptor
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1 ; 3. set 32-bit mode bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_32bit ; 4. far jump by using a different segment

    jmp $

[bits 32]
init_32bit:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; 5. update the segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000 ; 6. update the stack right at the top of the free space
    mov esp, ebp

    call BEGIN_32BIT
    jmp $

BEGIN_32BIT:
    jmp 0x1000:0x0000 ; Give control to the kernel
    jmp $

[bits 16]   
load_kernel:
    mov ah, 0x02     
    mov al, 3        
    mov ch, 0        
    mov dh, 0        
    mov cl, 2        
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]  ; use the boot drive
    int 0x13  
    jc disk_error   

    ret

disk_error:
    ; Display error message
    mov si, error_msg
    call print_string
    hlt

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E     
.print_char:
    lodsb            ; Load byte at DS:SI into AL and increment SI
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 0x10         
    jmp .print_char
.done:
    ret

loading_msg db 'Loading kernel...', 0
debugg_msg db 'Kernel loaded.', 0
debugg_msg2 db 'Loading GDT...', 0
debugg_msg3 db 'Switching to 32-bit mode...', 0
error_msg db 'Disk read error!', 0

BOOT_DRIVE db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0  
dw 0xAA55 

gdt.asm
gdt_start: 
    dd 0x0 
    dd 0x0 

gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0000    ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x00      ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x00      ; segment base, bits 24-31

gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0000
    db 0x00
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x00

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

Why does my bootloader halt after the "Loading GDT..." message?
(I am using qemu for testing: qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=disk.img,index=0,if=floppy)

I don't recognise the assembler syntax: what does %include 'gdt.asm' do? Does it include the GDT data inline at that point in the code segment? Because the processor is going to try and execute it, and that's not what you want.

I'm also suspicious of your CODE_SEG calculation. That doesn't look the right way to compute a segment offset to me, let alone an absolute segment to use in CODE_SEG:init_32bit. Also your two GDT entries look identical to me?

Is it possible to step through this using qemu as a debugger? I'd expect there's a way to debug emulated code.

@Rup This is NASM code. And indeed the include directive places the GDT within the path of the code flow, which will cause a crash. CODE_SEG and DATA_SEG are correct for calculating the GDT selectors however. Besides, the "flags" byte of the two descriptors does not match.

@ecm Thanks! Fair enough: in the 16-bit world segments were blocks of 16 bytes I think so I'd have expected at least a divide-by-16 if you were going to use it for jmp CODE_SEG:init_32bit - if indeed you can put an absolute segment in a jump like that - but I'm years out of date.

@Rup An absolute segment in a far immediate jump is indicated by two colon-separated immediates in NASM, as described in their old instruction reference. So that's correct. Once bit 0 of CR0 is set, the "segment" part is actually a selector into the GDT so the literal selector value is not related to Real/Virtual 86 Mode segments or paragraphs (16-byte chunks) any longer.

@Rup, you were right. The %include 'gdt.asm' directive only contained data, which caused the code to halt because it was trying to execute data instead of instructions. I moved the %include to the end of the code and adjusted the program's flow and logic accordingly. After making these changes, it worked. Thank you!

@estera: You can post an answer to your own question explaining what happened.  Then click the check mark and this question will be marked as answered.
